# Styles to elements are not applied by media query

Tags: html, css, media-queries

I am new at web development and I faced the confusion with certain styles not being applied at certain viewport size. So, what I wanted to apply is the font size to all elements inside the container, that is, as you can see in the code below:

**Html**

```
<div class="nav-container">
    <h1><span class="buy">Buy</span>Books<span class="books">Books</span></h1>
    <nav class="navbar" style="margin:0;">
            <ul class="links" style="margin:0;">
                <li><b><a href="#"> Home</a></b></li>
                <li><a href=""> <b>Category</b></a></li>
                <li><a href=""> <b>Books</b></a></li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
        <div class="cart"><a href=""> <i class="fas fa-shopping-cart fa-2x"></i></a></div>
    </div>
```

**CSS**

```
 @media (max-width:1200px){

 html{
        font-size:1.4rem;
    }
    .nav-container {
        font-size: 1rem;
    }

}
```

But this works

```
 @media (max-width:1200px){

        .nav-container h1 {
            font-size: 1rem;
        }

    }
```

As you can see the media query, if I target container it does not work but if I target specific element in that container it works ok. Why is that? The same issue with html in that media query which also is not applied. Please help I am a bit confused.

Answer (score 3):

It is because rem values are relative to the root html element, not to the parent element. That is, If font-size of the root element is 16px then 1 rem = 16px for all elements. If font-size is not explicitly defined in root element then 1rem will be equal to the default font-size provided by the browser (usually 16px).

In your second css you are giving to the h1 higher priority and you are rewriting the user agent stylesheet - Default browser settings.

[source](https://medium.com/code-better/css-units-for-font-size-px-em-rem-79f7e592bb97)

Answer (score 1):

This is because of something called the "user agent stylesheet". This contains all of the default styles for your browser. In the case of the `h1` element, you can see the default styles [here](https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/blink/+/master/Source/core/css/html.css#152).

The reason the first style isn't being applied is because you're relying on *inheritance*. Most elements will inherit inherit styles from their parents. Since the `font-size` for `h1` elements been specified in the user agent style sheet, it won't inherit the `font-size`.

The second style is applied because it has higher *specificity* than the user agent style. You can read about css selector specificity [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity). You could also override the style of `h1` elements by using the following declaration:

```
h1 {
  font-size: 1rem;
}
```

This would be applied because it was declared later than the user agent styles, so the browser prefers it.